# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

Strange error. I have a gridview which I've added pagination to.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" PageSize="3" GridLines="None" EmptyDataText="No data available." ShowHeader="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton" runat="server" Text="Add"></asp:LinkButton><br />
```

It loads the first page fine, however, if I try to go to page 2, 3 it gives me the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to
>   type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.

```
    protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {

    GridViewRow Row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer); //error 

        if (e.CommandName == "Add")
                    {    
                       .... 
        }
}

 protected void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
```

I thought it was because the `GridViewRow` was outside the `e.CommandName` so I moved it inside, however, this just displayed "No Data Available" message when I clciked on paginations.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it now, the problem was in the PageIndexChanging. As I have a public class for Binding The Grid, I called that instead of gv.DataBind.

```
protected void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }
```